# Insert a new path to a website with a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to extend a website with a new URL using a chrome extension, so I expect anyone with the extension to be able to access the extended path. Eg,

Eg, my extension will only work on "example.com" and I want to listen and catch when the browser hits "example.com/foobar". Is this possible?

I am able to append the URL with a link, while on "example.com", using history.pushState, and then on my extensions background script, I can listen to URL change and react accordingly.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.url) {
    if(changeInfo.url.indexOf("foobar") != -1) {
      // do my stuff here
    }
  }
});
```

However, this only works If I push the URL through javascript, eg, if you are on a /foobar page, doing a page refresh results with 404, as the original server doesn't have that path. I'd like to capture that request and generate a response myself through the extension.

Is there a more appropriate API/method to achieve this?

Comment: Yep, use chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest

Comment: Hey, thanks @wOxxOm, I think that will do the trick for me, I need a bit more testing tho. If you can provide that as an answer, I'll approve it.